# ListView isn't existing in navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, navigation-drawer

My ListView isn't coming up in android studio

I need to make a listView in navigation drawer activity's one page
I also need to know how to take an element's id in from another  .xml file
I need to use id of  imageView in app_content_main.xml file

Which layout is android studio showing? I can't realize it. is it appbar_main.xml file or content.main.xml file. It is considering content.xml file in appbar_main.xml file, but not listView

here is my code in Mainactivity.java file:

```
package com.example.sede;
enter code here

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.sede.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    ListView Habits = findViewById(R.id.Habits);
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("My name");
  names.add("My name");
    names.add("My name");
    names.add("My name");
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,                                         
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
 Habits.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Habits.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });




    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
 }
```

this one is in appbar_main.xml file :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SEDE.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.SEDE.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is in content_main.xml file:

```
enter code here
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addingHabit"
    style="@style/round"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="270dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Habits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="Today's plans"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

Comment: Data is missing when create the adapter, should be `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);`.